# Python click module is_flag not working as expected

Tags: python

According to click [documentation](http://click.pocoo.org/6/options/#boolean-flags) there are two ways to specific a boolean flag. The "on/off" method:

```
@click.option('--shout/--no-shout', default=False)
```

and the "is_flag" method:

```
@click.option('--shout', is_flag=True)
```

I am not getting this behavior. First the code.

```
import click


@click.command()
@click.option('--one/--no-one', default=False, help='on/off')
@click.option('--two', is_flag=False, help='is_flag')
def foo(one, two):
    print(one, two)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo()
```

The session below shows that the second option, "two", is a string argument not a boolean flag.

```
$ python foo.py --help
Usage: foo.py [OPTIONS]

Options:
  --one / --no-one  on/off
  --two TEXT        is_flag
  --help            Show this message and exit.
$ python foo.py --two
Error: --two option requires an argument
$ python foo.py --two a
False a
$ python foo.py --one
True None
$ python foo.py --no-one
False None
```

Am I using this incorrectly?

I am using click 6.7 and:

```
$ python --version
Python 3.5.3 :: Anaconda 4.4.0 (x86_64)
$ uname -a
Darwin tardis 16.7.0 Darwin Kernel Version 16.7.0: Fri Apr 27 17:59:46 PDT 2018; root:xnu-3789.73.13~1/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64
```

Comment: You have specified `is_flag=False`, so of course it's not a flag?

Answer (score 3):

You have specified `is_flag=False` which means it is not a flag. Change the click option for two to:

```
@click.option('--two', is_flag=True, help='is_flag')
```